# Legacy Access application of 30-40 forms , asp.net web matrix or web forms?

Tags: webforms, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I've been tasked with converting a legacy Access application over to a .net framework solution as quickly as possible.I'm unsure which approach approach to go for. I prefer asp.net web pages with web matrix as I'm comfortable in this environment but not sure if its the correct approach/best tool for the job. I know that web forms is good for grid based screens which this access application uses rather heavily.

I will be using SQL Server for the backend.

Has anyone moved an access application over to a .net framework solution before? If so what approach do you recommend? ASP.net Webpages Web matrix or Web forms? Something else?

Thanks
D

Answer (score 0):

If you are more comfortable with Web Pages, then use that. I have been playing with Web Pages and Knockoutjs recently. That might be a good combination: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/190/Using-Knockout-With-Razor-Web-Pages-In-WebMatrix-2

Comment: Thanks Mike, looks interesting, will check it out